# Custom Tool is not showing View, Laravel Nova

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I just followed all the  steps to make a custom Tool  [Laravel/Nova/custom/tools](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/customization/tools.html) But it doesn't show the default view,  there are not console error(js) or php error but the view is empty.
  [image]

```
 

    namespace Mihrbi\CompanyConfig;

    use Laravel\Nova\Nova;
    use Laravel\Nova\Tool;

    class CompanyConfig extends Tool
    {
        /**
         * Perform any tasks that need to happen when the tool is booted.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function boot()
        {
            // Nova::script('company-config', __DIR__.'/../dist/js/tool.js');
            // Nova::style('company-config', __DIR__.'/../dist/css/tool.css');
            Nova::serving(function (ServingNova $event) {
                Nova::script('company-config', __DIR__.'/../dist/js/tool.js');
                Nova::style('company-config', __DIR__.'/../dist/css/tool.css');
            });
        }

        /**
         * Build the view that renders the navigation links for the tool.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\View\View
         */
        public function renderNavigation()
        {
            return view('company-config::navigation');
        }
    }
```

those are the only changes I made, to use Nova::serving to avoid  "nova-api/scripts/company-config 500 (Internal Server Error)"

[image]

That happen when I remove the Nova::serving and npm run prod

local.ERROR: file_get_contents(/home/site/nova-components/CompanyConfig/src/../dist/css/tool.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

here my package.json

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^5.0.0",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.0"
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Delete the `Nova::serving` line and run `npm run prod` inside the root directory of the tool so that it publishes the JS and CSS files in the `dist` folder

Comment: Thanks but I tried that and it result in two error 500.  local.ERROR: file_get_contents(/home/site/nova-components/CompanyConfig/src/../dist/css/tool.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Post your package.json file. Perhaps the file is named something else

Comment: Done, I added it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my english. You must run `webpack.mix.js` inside your tool. When you run `npm run dev` or `npm run prod` laravel run own `webpack.mix.js`. If you want run tool `webpack.mix.js`. Enter your tool directory and run `npm run prod`. Like this. `cd nova-components/[Your tool folder name] && npm run dev`. Another short way. You can run command as script name (You can find `package.json`). Like this `npm run build-[your tool name]`.

Your solution:

1. run `cd nova-components/CompanyConfig && npm run dev`

OR

2. run  `npm run build-company-config`